# How do I structure a recombee catalog with multiple item types?

Tags: recommendation-engine

we are just getting started with recombee and are loading in our catalog.  We have different classes of items, like books, videos and games.  Should we be creating a separate catalog for each or one catalog with all the items and a type field to indicate the type of item?  We will want to provide recommendations both within a type (e.g. recommended books) as well as across types (e.g. recommended books, videos and games).
Thanks!  I couldn’t quite find the answer from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to recommend also across types, all the items should be in one Recombee database.

You should [add a string item property](https://docs.recombee.com/api.html#add-item-property) called `type` and [set it](https://docs.recombee.com/api.html#set-item-values) for each item (to *book*/*video*/*game* ...).

Then you can filter upon the property using [ReQL](https://docs.recombee.com/reql.html) by setting `filter` parameter of a [recommendation request](https://docs.recombee.com/api.html#recommendations). For example with filter: `'type' == "book"`, only books will be returned as recommended items.

If you don't set the filter, you will get recommended items of any type.